# I can't change homepage for my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to change the homepage for my WordPress website which is [www.jubinavchadha.com](http://www.jubinavchadha.com) I want it to be [www.jubinavchadha.com/home](http://www.jubinavchadha.com/home). I searched on internet and did all the things that it said I tried changing the static page function tried it from the reading section from settings. And even tried directory index function but it was causing many problems like it was working on Firefox but not on chrome. And is there any way to find out the page name and path in file manager where we land when we type the domain of a website (talking for the owner perspective) because if I know the path of the file that is currently the homepage I can put a redirect code on that page and that can solve my problem

this is my htaccess code

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you actually created a page called home?

Comment: yup you can go to the website and see it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script in your htaccess file. put it on top. see if it solves your problem.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home/ [L,R=303]
```

Comment: i just added my htaccess code can you please have look at it and tell me if anythings causing this issue

Comment: thats the default wordpress code in your htaccess file. add the code i provided above all of it. also in wordpress reading settings make sure you have not selected the Home as your home page dropdown option.